# What's the best way to implements multi language into the app?

Tags: nativescript

I am developing my app (for android and ios) using nativescript and I have a question, my app will be used for many users around the world so I want to add the support for "chose the language" according the user.

What is the best way to support many language for my string values into the app? I tried to found some example about that but I can't find any information about the stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe Dan Tamas is working on a plugin for this at the moment.
https://github.com/rborn/nativescript-i18n

Answer (score 2):

This might be not the best way but I hope it could help if you are in urgent.

I have implemented multi-language successfully in my app by using [Jed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jed) which is the Javascript implementation of [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) .

Things to do are:

- Install npm package jed + po2json
- Prepare PO files and compile to json
- Implements to XML pages by getting the source property from view-model

You can find more detail here:

[How to internationalize app in NativeScript](http://tech.smarp.com/dinh/localization-and-internationalization-on-nativescript/)